# Change the color of the last cell when mouse hovers over a row, value being taken into consideration

Tags: css

I'm trying to make like this:
If mouse hovers over a row, the last cell becomes red or yellow depending on the value: 1 or 0.

Well, I thought classes could help me: redcell and yellowcell are added.

I am inspired by this: http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/1/
My by code doesn't work.

Is it possible with CSS or not?

```css
        tr:hover ~ .redcell {
            background: red;
        }
        tr:hover ~ .yellowcell {
            background: red;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
    


   </head>

   <body>
      <table id="table">
        <tr>
          <td>item1</td>
          <td>item2</td>
          <td>item3</td>
          <td class="yellowcell">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>item1</td>
          <td>item2</td>
          <td>item3</td>
          <td class="redcell">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>item1</td>
          <td>item2</td>
          <td>item3</td>
          <td class="yellowcell">1</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try something like `tr .redcell:hover` or `td.redcell:hover`.

Comment: No you if you need specific number for specific color it is not possible with only CSS you have to add little bit of JS for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need child combinator selector:

```
tr:hover > .redcell {
            background: red;
        }
        tr:hover > .yellowcell {
            background: yellow;
        }
```

```css
 tr:hover > .redcell {
            background: red;
        }
        tr:hover > .yellowcell {
            background: yellow;
        }
```

```html
 <table id="table">
        <tr>
          <td>item1</td>
          <td>item2</td>
          <td>item3</td>
          <td class="yellowcell">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>item1</td>
          <td>item2</td>
          <td>item3</td>
          <td class="redcell">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>item1</td>
          <td>item2</td>
          <td>item3</td>
          <td class="yellowcell">1</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#table tr:nth-child(1):hover .yellowcell,#table tr:nth-child(3):hover .yellowcell {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#table tr:nth-child(2):hover .redcell  {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
    


   </head>

   <body>
      <table id="table">
        <tr>
          <td>item1</td>
          <td>item2</td>
          <td>item3</td>
          <td class="yellowcell">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>item1</td>
          <td>item2</td>
          <td>item3</td>
          <td class="redcell">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>item1</td>
          <td>item2</td>
          <td>item3</td>
          <td class="yellowcell">1</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```